# Why does "-Cy" become "-Sy"?

Tags: etymology, word-usage, language-change

What rule of grammar, or etymological history, makes "prophe-cy" (noun) become "prophe-sy" (verb)? What causes the C to become an S when the word usage changes?

Answer (score 9):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, the differentiation between prophecy and prophesy as noun and verb, respectively, happened more or less arbitrarily; before circa 1700, both variants were used for both noun and verb each:

> ME. a. OF. *prophecier* (1245 in Godef.), -*phesier, -fecier, -ficier,* f. *prophecie*, -*fecie* prophecy. The modern differentiation of *prophesy* vb. and *prophecy* n. was not established till after 1700, and has no etymological basis, *prophesy* being at first a mere spelling variant in both n. and vb.

The reason why this pair exists, while either c or s was chosen for both forms in other Greek words, is most probably confusion about which Greek word they were derived from. Normally, Greek -tia results in English -cy/cie, while Greek -sis results in English -sy/se/sis (both through French). This development is probably related to two facts:

- C and s have long been pronounced the same before y, so that they are easily confused. Vitaly has automatically compiled a list of words of Greek origin that have been found to occur with either spelling in major dictionaries; this illustrates how c and s were often interchangeable in the past. Note that most, if not all, of these words are now only spelled either -cy or -sy. Note also that one could no doubt find many more searching the Oxford English Dictionary for alternate spellings by hand.

> acracy/acrasy, apostacy/apostasy, eustacy/eustasy, idiosyncracy/idiosyncrasy, isostacy/isostasy, prophecy/prophesy, syncracy/syncrasy, theocracy/theocrasy

- Most Latin and Greek words first came to us through French, in which *-ti-* was often softened to -ci-. The original Greek word was *prophêteia*, which would normally result in -c- in (Old) French; that is probably where *prophecy* came from. The -t- in Greek is there because the word is derived from *prophêtes* ("prophet").

But a more common way of forming a word with a similar meaning from the same verb stem (*phê-*) in Greek would be *prophêsis* (cf. *haerêsis => heresy*); from this, the French derivation would result in *-sie, -se, or -sis* (though *-sis* is rather modern, as it is the exact Latin transcription of the Greek word). *Prophêsis* did not exist in classical Greek, because their only word for prophecy and the action of prophesying was not derived directly from the verbal stem, but from the noun *prophêtes* as above. But ignorance of this fact is probably what led people to spell -s- sometimes.

Perhaps certain writers thought the s was closer to the Greek and preferred it, especially in the verb, because they though it was -t- in the Greek noun and -s- in the Greek verb (which is not true). Or perhaps the differentiation developed for even more arbitrary reasons.

Answer (score 4):

[These guidelines](http://www.englishgrammar.org/spelling-rules-part-ii/) are applicable in British English:

> When two words, verb and noun, are spelt alike, “se” and “sy” are verb
>   endings; “ce” and “cy” are noun endings. The following are therefore
>   verbs: *license*, *practise*, *prophesy*, *advise*.
>
> The following are nouns: *licence*, *practice*, *prophecy*, *advice*
>
> *Promise* is an exception to this rule. It is both verb and noun.
>
> This rule does not hold good when verb and noun are not spelt alike,
>   so *suspense* and *hypocrisy* are nouns.

In American English, only *prophecy* (verb), *prophesy* (noun), *advise* (verb), and *advice* (noun) follow this guideline, with *licence* and *practise* being considered British spellings.

Comment: *Promise* is an exception to this rule. It is a noun. **And a verb.**

Comment: +1 Your point seems reasonable—that the often observed differentiation between -ce "noun" and -se "verb" may have influenced the prophecy–prophesy differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

No rule whatever. It just is. The OED says

> The modern differentiation of *prophesy* as the standard spelling of the verb vs. *prophecy* as the standard spelling of the noun was not established until the 18th cent. Before c1700, both types are frequent as spelling variants of both the noun and the verb.